# Excel: grouping by month

Tags: excel, pivot-table

In Excel grouping data by month and year using Pivot Tables is not very effective. For example it's not possible to calculate IRR on the pivot and if copied and pasted in another interval "gen", "feb" are just text and not dates.

Is there any workaround?

[image]

Comment: One alternative is to calculate the date in a helper column using `DateValue`and `Concat` functions

Comment: Showing the formula you would like to apply and a picture of what your expected results would be, will increase the chances of getting an answer.